# How do I incorporate offchain data into my contract in Remix?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I want a very simple example, maybe a function in a solidity contract that returns any value from an off-chain data source. Basically, I'm asking how to incorporate oracles into a contract, because I cannot for the life of me figure out how.  I've downloaded Truffle, Ganache, Web3, etc. What environment should I be doing this all in?  Is there a way to write JavaScript code in Remix? If not, where do I write my off-chain code and how do I integrate it with my contract I wrote in Remix?

Edit: I want some way to get off chain data into a smart contract.  I'll deal with getting a reliable data source later, but I want to know how to get up an environment where I can code in that can send data to a blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this on how to incorporate Oracles such as Chainlink and Amberdata into smart contracts in Remix:

https://medium.com/amberdata/the-definitive-guide-to-successfully-integrating-off-chain-data-into-your-ethereum-smart-contract-ec81d95ea441